# Ornithology related areas in Biology

Tags: ornithology

In relation to my work, I'm looking at ornithology as a field, and it would be interesting for me to know which areas in biology relate to ornithology.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Paleontology has paleo-ornithology as well, in fact dinosaur paleontology is very closely related.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can look at the papers published in the Journal of the Avian Biology, the Journal of Ornithology and the Auk. There you can see how bright is the field. It is about conservation biology, distribution of species, ecology of species, behavior, migration etc.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to figure that out is to look at what ornithologists are actually doing.  If you look up the staff page for an ornithological institute, you'll be able to see what type of projects they're involved in.

Here is an example:  [Percy FitzPatrick Institute of African Ornithology staff page](http://www.fitzpatrick.uct.ac.za/fitz/staff/)